# regular expression in sed replace question mark

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to replace all non-printable char and space and question mark to nothing.

`sed 's/[^[:print:]\|?\| \r\t]//g'`

but this will only replace non-printable char. The space and the question mark remains.

Comment: Why do you have two `|`'s in the character class? (Doesn't need to be escaped, btw.).

Comment: That will match anything that's not a printable character, pipe, question mark, space, carriage return or tab... doesn't seem like what you say you want. (And pipe, question mark and space are all printable characters so putting them in extra is just more redundancy)

Comment: @Shawn, isn't the pipe the 'OR' operator? it's not-printable, or ?, or space,

Comment: Basic regular expressions don't have alternation, and even in RE dialects that do, pipe is a plain character inside a bracket expression.

Comment: @Shawn, sorry, the [] contains OR logic already. so I modified it to 's/[^[:print:]\?\ \r\t]//g'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pipe in the bracket expression means a pipe, not an alternation operator.

You can use

```
sed -E 's/[^[:print:]]|[[:blank:]?]//g' file > outfile
```

Here,

- `-E` enables the POSIX ERE syntax
- `[^[:print:]]` - any non-printable char
- `|` - or (here, due to `-E` and the fact it is outside a bracket expression, it is an alternation operator
  `[[:blank:]?]` - a horizontal whitesapce or question mark.

You may chain two commands if you want to use POSIX BRE:

```
sed 's/[^[:print:]]//g;s/[[:blank:]?]//g' file > outfile
```